# sql query for getting unique value for the given values

Tags: sql, toad

[image]I have a table name CITY, having these two columns 'CITY_ID' and 'PLACES'

I'm trying to get CITY_ID which should have only these four places texas, alabama, arizona, colorado and it should not have any other places.

```
select city_id from city 
where places in ('texas','alabama','arizona','colorado')
having count(city_id)=4
group by city_id
```

Result : I'm getting many city_id which contains these four places and other places too.

pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following

```
SELECT C._city_id FROM
  (SELECT city_id, places, count(places) as numplaces FROM Cities group by city_id) as C
WHERE C.places in ('texas', 'alabama','arizona','colorado') AND C.numplaces = 4
```

Please note that my example was done in MySQL and that you will have to adapt the SQL if needed.

Comment: Can you give me example data, 2 or 3 rows as it would be in your database

Comment: Edited my post, try the example above

Comment: i have attached my data, i am expecting the result : CITY_ID 111, but i am getting all the city ID's

Answer (score 0):

select distinct city_id from city 
where places in ('texas','alabama','arizona','colorado');

should work.